# Hub SignalR Freezing at "Connecting" and Won't successfully connect - Asp.Net & Xamarin Form C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, signalr

my program won't run the next code because it stuck at /await hubConnection.StartAsync();/
i don't know why the Hub won't be connected successfully.

i tried to print out the error, and it shows that my program is still trying to connect to the hub, so it means that i'm stuck at /await hubConnection.StartAsync();/

This is my Hub & Xamarin C# code, plus error Picture: [image]. How do i fix this?

```
C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Get.Data;

namespace Get
{   

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public HubConnection hubConnection;
    public D d = new D();
  
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void GetButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        
        hubConnection = new 
    HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://10.0.2.2:36518/hubs").Build();
        //stucks
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();



        string infom = hubConnection.State.ToString();
        await DisplayAlert(infom, infom, infom);
    }

#Hub
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication6
{
public class Hubs : Hub
{
    public async void SendData(string b)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello world");
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("Get", b);
    }
}
}
#HubStartUp
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication6
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the 
    container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSignalR().AddHubOptions<Hubs>(options =>
        {
            options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request 
    pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<Hubs>("/hubs");
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: should it be `async *Task* GetButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

Comment: @oleksa i tried that "async Task GetButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)" but program said it's not the correct signature of Button

Comment: have you verified that the server is reachable from your device/emulator?  Can you reach it using the browser on the device/emulator?

Comment: @jason it is my local server, and it runs in browser normally

Comment: are you checking on the device/emulator, or on the desktop browser?  Those are completely different environments

Comment: @jason I run the Hub server with LLS express-google chrome(that has in ASP.Net)

Comment: you are not answering the question I asked.  Can you connect to the server IP from your **device/emulator** browser?

Comment: @Jason i tried it on Real Device browser it said "This site can't be reached. 10.0.2.2 took too long too respond. Try: Checking the connection ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". And i tried it on Emulator browser it said "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid"

Comment: then you have a connectivity problem you need to fix.  By default IIS Express is not allowed to accept external requests, that might be the problem.

Comment: @Jason i really appreciated your advice, and i've been working really hard to find solution to fix this connectivity. Thank you

Comment: @Jason i am having a reachable webserver now, but when i run code at my client side it still stuck at await hubconnection.StartAsync(); i dont know what is the actual problem now

Comment: have you tested your hub using a SignalR tool or another test client?

Comment: @Jason Mr. Jason does this warning has anything to do with the connection to the Hub?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023517/warning-message-there-was-a-conflict-when-debugging-xamarin-form-signalr-clien

Comment: I doubt it.  Have you tested your hub like I suggested?

Comment: @Jason I'm trying to test it everyday like what you have suggested, but cant fix the problem yet

Comment: @Jason Mr. Jason i got a new exception error by running the code on an emulator.
'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'

Comment: did you look at the InnerException?