# Warning Message "There was a conflict" when debugging Xamarin Form SignalR Client C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dll, signalr

Whenever i debug my Xamarin form(Mobile, C#, SignalR.Client) the message below always pop out. Is this the reason why my client side can't connect to the Hub in Asp.Net Core? My hub does not work properly. I've been finding the error in my code, but this is the only thing that i found in my code. How do i fix this?

```
Message:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
        D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
            System.Numerics.Vectors
    References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll".
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connections.common\6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connections.client\6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client\6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\source\repos\App21\App21\App21\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App21.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.common\6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.core\6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll
            C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.protocols.json\6.0.0-preview.7.21378.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll  App21.Android
```

Comment: you need VS2022 preview to use .net 6 (preview7)

Comment: Great information. I will check this out!

Comment: I get exactly the same issue, but second reference is `C:\Users\usernm\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net 6 has not yet been released, so it is prone to errors. Additionally, VS2022 (Preview 3) would be better suited for debugging this issue as the environment has been created to work with preview builds of .Net 6. Try installing Preview 3 of VS2022 from here - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Like @magicandre1981 says, your issue likely stems from your use of .Net 6 while using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I tried checking it, and yes you are right. I will try to fix this one base on your advices!

Comment: So what was the fix? I get the same error, and I don't use .NET 6

Comment: This was apparently the fix for OP's situation. I'd start a new question if this fix didn't work for you, it may be different circumstances